# mongoose $gt operator in express typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to find users whose tokens have not expired yet.

```
try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      resetToken: passwordToken,
      resetTokenExpiration: { $gt: Date.now() },
      _id: userId,
    });
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundError();
    }
```

in plain javascript it had no issue. in typescript i am getting this error:

```
 Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date | undefined'.
```

typescript evaluates `$gt: Date.now()`  as type annotation. I am converting my node.js project to typescript and this is the only thing that I could not figure out.

Answer (score 1):

`Date.now()` returns an integer, UTC milliseconds from the epoch.  Use `new Date()` to get a `Date` object (it's still UTC on the inside).